# The preimage of the intersection of sigma-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S, T, I$ be non-empty sets, for every $i \in I$ let $\mathcal{A}_i$ be a sigma-algebra on $T$, and let $f:S\rightarrow T$. Is it true that $f^{-1}\big(\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathcal{A}_i\big) = \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}}f^{-1}(\mathcal{A}_i)$?

---

**Remarks**

1. It is known that $f^{-1}\big(\bigcap_{i \in I}B_i\big) = \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}}f^{-1}(B_i)$ if $B_i \subseteq T$ for every $i \in I$. But this result is not the same as what needs to be proved, since $\bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}}B_i \subseteq T$, whereas $\bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}}\mathcal{A}_i\subseteq\mathbb{P}T$.
2. I was able to show that $f^{-1}\big(\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathcal{A}_i\big) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}}f^{-1}(\mathcal{A}_i)$, so the question reduces to whether the converse containment is valid.

Comment: Preimages of a function$f$  act on sets in the range of $f$. I guess you meant to ask whether $\{f^{-1}(A): A\in \bigcap_i\mathcal{A}_i\}=\bigcap_i\{f^{-1}(A):A\in\mathcal{A}_i\}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz: You guessed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal A_1 =\{\emptyset, \Omega, A,A^{c}\}$ and $\mathcal A_2 =\{\emptyset, \Omega, B,B^{c}\}$ where $A=[0,\frac 1 2), B=[0,\frac 1 3)$. Then the left side is $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$. I leave it to you to find an $f$ for which $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B) $ ($\neq \emptyset, \neq \Omega$) so the right side contains $f^{-1}(A)$.